# Как вводить цифры, как при наборе пароля

Tags: python

Хочу, что бы при вводе цифр в input на экране были видны звёздочки как в паролях.

```
    password = '2508'
var = input('Ведите старый пароль')#здесь хочу вводить звёздочки


if var == password:
    var1 = input('Ведите новый пароль')
    print('Новый пароль', var1)
    var = var1

else:
    print('Пароль не верный')
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/getpass.html

Answer (score 0):

На английском stackoverflow есть уже ответ на ваш вопрос:

[ссилка](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9202224/getting-a-hidden-password-input)

Но вот готовое решение:

```
import getpass
pswd = getpass.getpass('Password:')
```